# How to retrieve all using items (indirectly using Components too) of a particular Component through the Core Service

Tags: 2011, core-service

I have a Component `A` which is embedded in another Component `B`. This nested behavior we may have up to 3 to 4 levels. Finally the last Component will be used on a Page.

My case is, I have to find the Page or published Component in publication level and republish them using the Core Service.

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, and a .Net client console application using the Core Service.

I have used the `UsingItemsFilterData` in the Core Service but it is returning me only the 1st level Components which are directly using Component `A`. Please let me know if there is any filter available which will help me with this?

Comment: When you say "embedded in", do you mean "linked from"?

Comment: Yes Dominic, To be specific component A is a multimedia component, and component B contains component A as Multimedia Link. And there will be a Component C which contains Component B as Component Link

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no perfect filter that does this.  The closest thing I can think of is the `ItemsFilterData` with the `Recursive` property to **True**.  However, this will simply get all the items in a given Publication/Folder/SG recursively through all nested subitems.

I think in your case you will need to get the ID of your level 1 Component, fetch that Component, get the ID of the next level and so on. Basically drill down until you get to the Component that's on a Page.

Comment: Thanks Nickoli, i am ready with this drill down recursive logic from client side as you said. I was just curious know if i am missing any recursive featured filter which will help me directly here.